how to clear the JOBS RUN details in the Patch window of GCP
I want to clear the data saved in the 'JOBS RUN' of the OS Patch Management in Google Cloud Platform. I could not see any option the GCP console as well as the no documentation found even for CLI.
Found no option to clear the jobs in JOBS RUN window

You cannot.
The service|API appears to provide no DELETE methods. I'm unfamiliar with this service but the absence of DELETE methods appears rational in that OS patches represent auditable events.
Compute Engine v1:

projects.patchJobs

projects.patchJobs.instanceDetails


Same-same for Compute Engine v1beta:

projects.patchJobs

And Compute Engine gRPC OsConfigService
